# Magento rwd custom theme add rounded corners compass

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, rwd, scss

i am building a custom theme based on the default Magento 1.9 rwd-theme. What is the best way to add rounded corners (for my buttons etc)?

If have seen [this](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/border_radius), but how do i add them to my Magento theme?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find scss\module_catalog-product.scss

on line 386 ish? :
"    @include border-radius(1px 3px 5px 7px, 2px 4px 6px 8px) "

```
.add-to-cart-buttons .button {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: $f-size-xl;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    width: 100%;
    @include border-radius(1px 3px 5px 7px, 2px 4px 6px 8px)
```

}